picamera2 issue with rpicam3 on pi4
i have a new rpi4B with bookworm 64bit.
i have an rpicam3.
i am trying to capture a still using python picamer2.
i can run libcamera-hello and i see video fine.
when i run a simple python file to capture still i get noise. i am not sure if i am not setting some controls on an rpiv3 like exposure or something.
i have gone in circles trying different examples. Here is what doesnt work. i dont see any errors on terminal btw. I am also on a small hdmi monitor.
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
from libcamera import controls
import time
picam2 = Picamera2()
config = picam2.create_still_configuration({"size":(800,600)})
picam2.configure(config)
picam2.start()
time.sleep(1)
picam2.capture_file('test.jpeg')

please any help would be appreciated.

i was able to fix this by running apt upgrade. I assumed since it was a new image it was up to date but that apparently fixed it.
